# Getting Started with Paper Element Theming in Polymer

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to learn how to use [Paper Elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) within [Polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/). When I add basic elements like a button, they are not styled properly. I see a button shape with a shadow. However, I cannot get any colors to appear. Everything is just white. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">    

    <script src="res/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>         
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/polymer/polymer.html"> 

    <!-- Iron Elements -->    
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/iron-signals/iron-signals.html">

    <!-- Paper Elements -->
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">

    <!-- Neon Elements -->    
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
    <link rel="import" href="res/components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">
  </head>

  <body class="fullbleed">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="vertical layout center-justified">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>

        <paper-button tabindex="0" on-click="_onLoginButtonClick" raised class="colorful custom">Login</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-click="_onSignUpButtonClick">Sign Up</paper-button>
      </div>                    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to show just a blue button that is consistent with the material design theme. So, I added `raised class="colorful"` as shown in the demo. However, I do not get a blue button. When I looked at the [code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/blob/master/demo/index.html) on GitHub, I noticed that they seem to be defining ALL of the color classes in the style section.

Is there a way to just bring in theme? Or do I have to actually define all of the colors?

Thanks

Comment: Does something like https://polymerthemes.com/sky/ work for you?. All you have to do is download the files and use them.

Comment: @Ajinkya Wow! That is amazingly awesome. Thank you for sharing the site.